# Flask is parsing out AngularJS expressions

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

Using Python 3.4.1

Everything is working fine, otherwise.

For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things"><a href="#">{{thing}}</a></li>
```

will create elements of however many things I expect, and console is even logging my expected results... but when the html is rendered the expressions are removed and I'm met with a list of empty elements:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

I know this is an issue with Flask using the same curly-brace notation. Does anybody know how to get AngularJS expressions to render otherwise?

---

Tried both:

```
jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
jinja_options.update(dict(
    block_start_string='<%',
    block_end_string='%>',
    variable_start_string='%%',
    variable_end_string='%%',
    comment_start_string='<#',
    comment_end_string='#>',
))

app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = 'static'
```

and

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = 'static'
app.jinja_options.copy().update(dict(
    block_start_string='<%',
    block_end_string='%>',
    variable_start_string='%%',
    variable_end_string='%%',
    comment_start_string='<#',
    comment_end_string='#>',
))
```

using the tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%% url_for('static', filename='js/lib/angular.min.js') %%"></script>
```

just renders it as-is without interpreting the delimiters. Leads to a bunch of 404's obviously.

---

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = 'static'
app.jinja_options.update(dict(
    variable_start_string='%%',
    variable_end_string='%%'
))
```

and

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = 'static'
app.jinja_options.update(
    variable_start_string='%%',
    variable_end_string='%%'
)
```

both give `TypeError: 'ImmutableDict' objects are immutable`

Changing my angular expressions to `{{'{{thing}}'}}` works but I'd just as soon switch to a different framework than have to manage my angular code like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `jinja_options`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

jinja_options = app.jinja_options.copy()
jinja_options.update(dict(
    block_start_string='<%',
    block_end_string='%>',
    variable_start_string='%%',
    variable_end_string='%%',
    comment_start_string='<#',
    comment_end_string='#>',
))
app.jinja_options = jinja_options
```

In a template:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things"><a href="#">{{thing}}</a></li>
%% jinja_expression %%
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. `<script type="text/javascript" src="%% url_for('static', filename='js/lib/angular.min.js') %%"></script>` just renders as-is and, of course, 404's

Comment: Just updated the answer to solve the ```ImmutableDict``` problem.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't jinja support syntax like this?

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things"><a href="#">{{{{thing}}}}</a></li>
```

That works in django at least and I'd expect that jinja allows escaping braces in this way as well.

Comment: Close, found it. It's actually {{'{{thing}}'}}

Comment: Ahh, it must be a bit different.